# Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender

Tags: email, spam

Just wondering if there is any way to change the mail subject "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender" to something else, if the error code is 550.

If no then is there is any way to detect a correct email.I am not saying about the email validation.That part is ok.But sometimes if there is no mail box then we get 550 error code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

SMTP reply code 550 means:

> The requested command failed because the user's mailbox was
>   unavailable (for example because it was not found, or because the
>   command was rejected for policy reasons).

Double check your email settings.

On the other hand, the default error reporting email subject is fixed and you cannot be changed, as it is set in remote email server.

Reference: [List of SMTP Server Response Codes](http://email.about.com/cs/standards/a/smtp_error_code_2.htm)

Comment: Thanks Shivan.Actually my question is how can I change the subject of the email which I am getting if there is no email box.The subject is "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender"

Comment: oh. The default error reporting email subject is fixed and you cannot be changed, as it is set in remote email server.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: I have voted your comment but sorry can't accept the answer.Hope you understand why.Thanks.